# Mocked response is not displayed in a component

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, ts-jest

I am trying to test this sample functional component in react:

```
const DisplayFruits: React.FC = () : JSX.Element => {
   const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
   const [fruits, setFruits] = useState<Array<fruitInterface>|null>(null);

   useEffect(() -> {
      const listFruits = async(): Promise<void> => {
         const result: Array<fruitInterface> = await UTILS.getFruits();
         console.log(result);
         setFruits(result);
         setLoading(false);
       };
      listFruits();
   }, []);

   return (
      {loading ? <div><LoadingIcon /> </div> : 
      <div> // display list of fruits </div>}
   );
};
```

Below you can find my test attempt:

```
it('Should render fruit data', () => {
   UTILS.getFruits = jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(Promise.resolve(mockFruitData));
   const wrapper = mount(<DisplayFruits />);
   console.log(wrapper.debug());
});
```

The console log from DisplayFruits component shows that the mocked fruit data is visible, but according to wrapper.debug() the component still renders with LoadingIcon, not the data I want to see. Can you please help me and spot where I am making a mistake?

Comment: Listing the fruits is asynchronous, you have to wait for the component to update.

Comment: @jonrsharpe oh my, you are right! Thank you sooo much, it works now.